# VBA find and replace skipping some cells

Tags: excel, replace, vba

I have a bit of code that finds blanks in a given column and replaces them with "BLANK", this has worked fine in the past and works for all of the sheets I am looking at bar one.

In the 'meter' sheet the whole column is blank, yet the find and replace fills all bar 6 of the blanks with no apparent pattern as below. I expect this could be another of my Monday morning 'user malfunction' errors but would appreciate any insight.

I am aware this would be better in a loop, which I will write once I've fixed the problem of it missing some blanks.

Cheers

```
Public Function FILL_blanks() '''' this searches for blanks 
'in the columns in the raw data we are interested in and replaces 
'them with BLANK there is a value assigned to BLANK in the flag matrix.

Dim LastRow_g As Long '''' HYDRANT, NODE ---->CHANGES LENGTH FOR EACH ASSET
Dim LastRow_j As Long ''''
Dim LastRow_bp As Long ''''
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim i As Integer

WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For i = 1 To WS_Count
    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name = "hydrant" Then
        Worksheets(i).Select 
        Range("g4").Select ' this will change j/g/bp only 
        LastRow_g = Range("g" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'define the last row as all of the rows in DMA flag column
        Range("r4:r" & LastRow_g).Select

        'find and replace below
        Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="BLANK", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False

    ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name = "meter" Then

        Worksheets(i).Select
        Range("j4").Select 
        LastRow_j = Range("j" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'define the last row 
        Range("y4:y" & LastRow_j).Select 

        'find and replace below
        Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="BLANK", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: what do you mean by "bar one" and "bar 6"?

Comment: I suspect that there is some code missing above... for example, variable `LastRow_bp` is unused, and the `If` statement has no closing `End`

Comment: Also, look carefully at column J on your "meter" worksheet.  Where is the last row there?  And are any of the rows hidden, either manually or by a filter?

Comment: Ron, I meant except when I said bar.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Sub` here rather than `Function` because there doesn't seem to be a return. This code replaces blank cells in the columns specified above:

```
Option Explicit
Sub FillBlanks2() '''' this searches for blanks

Dim LastRow As Long '''' HYDRANT, NODE ---->CHANGES LENGTH FOR EACH ASSET
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim TargetRange As Range

'loop through worksheets in this workbook
For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Sheet.Name = "hydrant" Then '<~ concerned with col G on hydrant sheet
        With Sheet
            LastRow = .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set TargetRange = .Range(.Cells(4, 7), .Cells(LastRow, 7))
        End With
        'apply replacement to the target range
        TargetRange.Replace What:="", Replacement:="BLANK", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows
    ElseIf Sheet.Name = "meter" Then '<~ concerned with col J on hydrant sheet
        With Sheet
            LastRow = .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set TargetRange = .Range(.Cells(4, 10), .Cells(LastRow, 10))
        End With
        'apply replacement to the target range
        TargetRange.Replace What:="", Replacement:="BLANK", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows
    End If

Next Sheet

End Sub
```

Comment: AFAIK, in VBA, using a Function instead of a Sub does not have any drawback.

Comment: Good point @iDevlop, I suppose my recommendation was more of a convention than a syntactical requirement. In my experience, `Function` is normally used when something is returned. What are your thoughts and recommendations on `Function` vs `Sub`?

Comment: If any doubt, use Function. You can always call it like a Sub, but reverse not true. Other advantage: a same Function can be invoked from several form events by using `=MyFunction()` syntax. And at least you can always return True/False to indicate Success/Error.

Comment: That looks good thanks Dan, I will test it later on and let you know if it works, looks like it will do the trick nicely

Comment: I altered the loop you gave me above to relate to the columns I was interested in and the loop works fine but the source of my problem is actually that some of my data columns contain spaces rather than blanks, is there a way to code in replace blanks or spaces?

Comment: You can use `.Trim` on `String` to clean up trailing/leading spaces, otherwise you can adjust the `TargetRange.Replace` to use `What:=" "`

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the code from Dan Wagner to account for cells that appear blank but actually have spaces in them. if the cells are only likely to contain a blank or one space then it is possible to use "" and " ".

However, I am sure there is a more elegant solution that accounts for all blank spaces. SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) is a possibility but it appears to be limited to a certain number of rows.

```
    Sub FILL_blanks() '''' this searches for blanks

Dim LastRow As Long '''' HYDRANT, NODE ---->CHANGES LENGTH FOR EACH ASSET
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim TargetRange As Range

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
            LastRow = Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set TargetRange = Range("b4:b" & LastRow)

            'apply replacement to the target range
            '"" accounts for true blank cells (no spaces)
            ' "*" is a wildcard and accounts for one or more spaces

        TargetRange.Replace What:="", replacement:="BLANK", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows
        TargetRange.Replace What:=" ", replacement:="BLANK", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows

End Sub
```

Thanks again for your assistance

Comment: However, this will replace any characters in the cell.